# Taking out number of subarrays from an array which contains all the distinct elements of that array

Tags: c

My teacher gave me a homework problem in which a user would provide an array with its size.

What we have to do is:-

> 1) Take out all the distinct elements from that array.
>
> 2) Compare all the subarrays which are possible in the main array with
>   the "distinct array".
>
> 3) Tell the number of times we were able to successfully "discover"
>   all those subarrays which contained ALL the distinct elements.

Example:- We are given an array :- [1,2,2,3,3]
The distinct elements array would be :- [1,2,3]
All the subarray of the original array will be :-

```
1) [1,2]
2) [1,2,2]
3) [1,2,2,3]
4) [1,2,2,3,3]   
5) [2,2]
6) [2,2,3]
7) [2,2,3,3]
8) [2,3]
9) [2,3,3]
10) [3,3]
```

The answer of this specific test case shall be 2. Since only (3) and (4) subarrays contain all the distinct elements i.e. 1,2 and 3.

Second Example:-

Given array :- [86,5,34,64,56,60,81,77,36,41]

The answer of the second example is 1; since all the elements of the original array are distinct and hence only one solution shall contain all the possible distinct elements which is the original array itself.

Here is my code which I have wrote for the above problem:-

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdbool.h>

bool check(int *, int *, int, int);


int main()
{
    int number; // Variable name "number" which will specify the size of dynamically allocated array.

    printf("Enter the size of your array\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);

    int *array;
    array = (int*)calloc(number, sizeof(int)); // Dynamically allocated memory.


    int *temp_array;
    temp_array = (int*)calloc(number, sizeof(int)); // Temporary variable of original array.

    int i,j=0; // Counter variables for loop.

    printf("Enter the elements of arrays\n");

    for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",(array + i)); //Main original array being filled.
    }

    for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        *(temp_array + i) = *(array + i); //Copying into temp.
    }



    for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        for( j = i + 1 ; j < number; j++)
        {
            if( *(temp_array + i ) == *(temp_array + j))
            {
                *(temp_array + j) = 0; // My way of removing those numbers which are the repeated. (Assigning them value of zero).
            }
        }
    }

    i=0;j=0;

    int sub_number = 0;

    while(i < number)
    {
        if(*(temp_array + i) != 0)
        {
            sub_number++; // Variable name "sub_number" which will specify the size of dynamically allocated array "sub_array".
        }
        i++;
    }

    int *sub_array ;
    sub_array = (int*)calloc(sub_number,sizeof(int));

    j=0;
    for(i = 0;i < number ;i++)
    {
        if( *(temp_array + i ) != 0)
        {
            *(sub_array + j) = * (temp_array + i ); //Transferring all the distinct values from temp_array to sub_array.
            j++;
        }
    }

    free(temp_array); //Freed "temp_array". No longer needed.
    temp_array = NULL;

    for(i = 0;i < sub_number; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(sub_array + i)); // Desired array which only contains distinct and unique variables.
    }

    printf("\n");

    //CODE IS CORRECT TILL THE ABOVE LINE AND HAS BEEN VERIFIED.

    //Problem code starts from below.

    int ans = 0;    //Variable which shall calculate the answer.
    int k=0;        //New variable counter
    j=0;


    for(i=0; i < number; i++) //This loop will traverse variable "i" on array "array".
    {
        k = i;
        while(k < number)   //This loop will traverse variable "k" on array "array"
        {
            int *new_array;
            new_array = (int*) calloc ((k-i+1),sizeof(int));

                for(j = i; j < k; j++)  //This loop will assign the subset values of array "array" to array "new_array".
                {
                    *(new_array + (j - i)) = *(array + j);
                }
                if(check(new_array, sub_array, (k-i+1), sub_number) == true) //This will check if ALL the values in "sub_array" are present in "new_array" or not.
                {
                    ans++;
                }

            free(new_array);
            new_array = NULL;
            k++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d",ans);

    return 0;
}

bool check(int * new_array, int *sub_array, int new_number, int sub_number) //Function to check if ALL the values in "sub_array" are present in "new_array" or not.
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < new_number; i++)     //new_number is nothing but (k - i + 1)
    {
        if(*(new_array + i)  == *(sub_array + j))
        {
            j++;
            if(j == sub_number)
            {
                return true;
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now the problem portion of my code (which i believe) starts from:-

```
    //CODE IS CORRECT TILL THE ABOVE LINE AND HAS BEEN VERIFIED.

    //Problem code starts from below.

    int ans = 0;    //Variable which shall calculate the answer.
    int k=0;        //New variable counter
    j=0;


    for(i=0; i < number; i++) //This loop will traverse variable "i" on array "array".
    {
        k = i;
        while(k < number)   //This loop will traverse variable "k" on array "array"
        {
            int *new_array;
            new_array = (int*) calloc ((k-i+1),sizeof(int));

                for(j = i; j < k; j++)  //This loop will assign the subset values of array "array" to array "new_array".
                {
                    *(new_array + (j - i)) = *(array + j);
                }
                if(check(new_array, sub_array, (k-i+1), sub_number) == true) //This will check if ALL the values in "sub_array" are present in "new_array" or not.
                {
                    ans++;
                }

            free(new_array);
            new_array = NULL;
            k++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d",ans);

    return 0;
}

bool check(int * new_array, int *sub_array, int new_number, int sub_number) //Function to check if ALL the values in "sub_array" are present in "new_array" or not.
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < new_number; i++)     //new_number is nothing but (k - i + 1)
    {
        if(*(new_array + i)  == *(sub_array + j))
        {
            j++;
            if(j == sub_number)
            {
                return true;
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The thing is that my code only outputs `0` and nothing else. Hence is there any problem with my `boolean` function? or the `if statement` which i have used above?

Comment: Why is the answer for [1, 2, 2, 3, 3] 2 when there are four subsets that contain all of the distinct elements: [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3], and [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]?

Comment: In `check`, after `i = 0;`, program control flows to the end of the `for` statement, which increments `i`, so the next loop begins with `i` set to 1, meaning no more checks are performed with `*(new_array + 0)`.

Comment: Write references to elements as `sub_array[j]`, not `*(sub_array + j)`, for readability.

Comment: What thing? The example? You found an example for your homework assignment on the net? Where?

Comment: Okay, the items in the problem are not **subsets** of the array (a subset is any collection of elements from a set) but **subarrays** of the array (portions of the array, so all elements from some start position to some end position). You should edit the question to use the correct word.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for telling me. I have edited the same.

Comment: The question does not state for what input the program outputs only “0”. What input reproduces the problem?

Comment: The loop to copy elements using `for(j = i; j < k; j++)` iterates from `i` to `k` including `i` but excluding `k`, but `k` is intended to be inside the subarray, as evidenced by the later count of elements `k-i+1` and by the bounds used to loop on k, `k = i;` and `while(k < number)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil for the second example mentioned above. For the first example it outputs `1`.

Comment: Fixing the two bugs above produces the correct output for the two test cases.

Comment: The `new_array = (int*) calloc ((k-i+1),sizeof(int));` could be removed, `check` doesn't modify the array, just `check(array + j, ..., (k-i+1),`. The `k = i;
        while(k < number) { ... k++;}` would look way cleaner as `for (k = i; k < number; k++)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you so much! I finally got both the bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 bugs in the code as pointed out in the comments below are :-

> The loop to copy elements using `for(j = i; j < k; j++)` iterates from `i` to `k` including `i` but excluding `k`, but `k` is intended to be inside the subarray, as evidenced by the later count of elements `k-i+1` and by the bounds used to loop on `k, k = i; and while(k < number)`.

and

> In check, after `i = 0`;, program control flows to the end of the `for` statement, which increments `i`, so the next loop begins with `i` set to `1`, meaning no more checks are performed with `*(new_array + 0)`